# ArgumentError with Cequel and Ruby3 / Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cassandra, cequel

I have updated a former project from Ruby 2.5 / Rails 5.2 to Ruby 3.0 and Rails 6.1
The server starts, but when I reached it, I have this error :
ArgumentError (Delegation needs a target. Supply a keyword argument 'to' (e.g. delegate :hello, to: :greeter).):

The line causing problem is : include Cequel::Record

I use the last version of Cequel.

Comment: I don't use Cequel or Cassandra but it looks like there's a conflict in the argument lists between [Cequel's version of `delegate`](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/blob/aac1d74b95f94848c5f9850380ddbf6e85c646a6/lib/cequel/util.rb#L68) and [ActiveSupport's version in Rails6](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate). Cequel doesn't seem to be ready for Rails6 and it doesn't seem to be [well maintained](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/issues/417) these days.